# Check if a network location exists, if yes, connect to it

Tags: python

I am trying to get some data from remote servers in my local network. So I have code, which at the moment looks something like this:

```
for p in paths:
    if not os.path.exists(p):
        os.system('net use /user:username '+p+' password')
    #Do some stuff with the data on the server
```

This code makes sure, that I authenticate on each server using "username" and "password" before accessing the data. The problem arises though, if one of the servers is down/offline. So I need something like this (pseudo-code):

```
for p in paths:
    if 'network location does not exist at all':
        #skip this server as it is offline
        continue
    if 'network location exists, but not connected':
        #Connect to this server
        os.system('net use /user:username '+p+' password')
    #Do some stuff with the data on the server
```

Unfortunately, I was not yet able to find a function which distinguishes the two cases. Neither `os.path.exists` nor `os.access` with any of its options can distinguish the two cases.

Comment: Such checks are never 100% reliable, because of [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). The only way to be sure that you can connect is to actually do it. So why not try to connect and handle the failure gracefully if the server is offline?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking this is a bad practice because it will create hard-to-track-down bugs in your code.

Consider the following code:

```
if os.path.isfile("somefile"):
    # some other program deletes the file
    with open("somefile") as f_handle: # KABOOM
        print(f_handle.read())
```

generally we don't even do that when reading *local files* much less something over a socket. Wrap your operation in a try/except and deal with the error if the server isn't there, and do this for any IO operation that can fail (e.g. file IO, network IO).

```
import json
import requests

try:
    req = requests.get("local/network/url")
    result = req.json()
    print(result)
except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
    # you got a bad response
    do_something_with_bad_server_response(err)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    # your request failed entirely
    fallback(err)
```

You may need to tweak this a bit, for example your server may not be returning JSON, but hopefully this gives the idea.

Comment: Hi, I understand, why you mean that I should use try/except. But still, I will not be able to reliably distinguish between the two cases. Sure, I can just use my code from the first example and then wrap all the `#Do some stuff with the data` in try/excepts and assume, that whenever I run into an except, that obviously my server was offline. And I will also probably do this, but I also think, this is not the cleanest way, especially as I am almost sure, that I always have one or two of the network locations being offline.

Comment: @SimonSchey it's not clear what you mean by "reliably distinguish between the two cases". What two cases? Your server is there or it isn't. The response was what you expected or it isn't. At any rate I updated my answer with some example code of what it might look like.

Comment: Even if you successfully connect, there is never a guarantee that you will *stay* connected and that whatever you are doing will succeed. All you can do is check that the actions you perform *do* succeed, and be prepared for if/when they don't.

Comment: @JaredSmith By "reliably distinguish" I mean, that I don't know of any function, that can differentiate between "my network drive is offline / unreachable" (where I cannot do anything except try again another time) and "I need to authenticate myself using net use..." (where I can do something, specifically authenticate myself), because e.g. `os.path.exists(p)` returns false in both cases. So my original code checks if my drive exists and then will authenticate if it doesn't. But if the problem was not, that I wasn't authenticated, but that the server is down, this statement is useless.